# VBA : Retrieve label value from HTML to MsgBox

Tags: vba, excel

I have following HTML code, that I want to retrieve data from:

```
<div class="span4">
    <div>
       <label for="Game_type">Portal Games</label>
         XXX
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Game_Reference">Game reference</label>
         22130903
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Release_Date">Release Date</label>
         2015-07-13
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Prise">Prise</label>
         USD 90,00
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Game_Rank">Game Rank</label>
          4
    </div>
</div>
```

How I am able to get all those label values/at least one value into MsgBox?. (Later I will input them into Excel myself)

I have tried using following code to get first value:

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")
'page address is stated in code
IE.navigate "page name" 
IE.Visible = True

While IE.Busy
'Wait until IE is busy and loading page
DoEvents
Wend

Set gtype = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("span4")(0).getElementsById("Game_type")
GtypeValue =  gtype.Value
MsgBox (GtypeValue)

End Sub
```

I received run-time error "91:"

> Object variable or With Block variable not set.

150904
Hopefully last one question, regarding this topic.Default code looks like

```
 strCont = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("span4")(0).innerHTML
```

But I want to have a variable instead of "span4", in example Dim1= "span4"
I state following:

```
strCont = "objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName(" & Chr(34) & Dim1 & Chr(34) & ")(0).innerHTML"
```

It does not work, empty value in MsgBox. How can I make sure that this sting will be counted as exact code to be executed later in step:

```
Set objMatches = .Execute(strCont)
```

Comment: Are you coding your VBA in Excel? And what line are you receiving the error on?

Comment: It seems the very first line of your subroutine is missing, is this the problem?

Comment: There are no id's in that HTML, so getElementById isn't going to do anything.  Try `getElementsByTagName("div")` instead: you'll need to loop over the returned collection.

Comment: @MatthewD - yes, In Excel. In line: Set gtype = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("span4")(0).getElementsById("Game_type")

Comment: @laylarenee - sorry, didnt understand your question

Comment: @Tim Williams - will try it out. Thank you

Comment: Could you please share the full code you are trying to get to work, put it next to "Default code looks like ...". It's not clear what is "empty value in MsgBox", show your test MsgBox in that code.

Comment: Try `strCont = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName(Dim1)(0).innerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to try regex for parsing?

```
Sub MsgGameType()
    Dim objIE As Object
    Dim strCont As String
    Dim objMatches As Object
    Dim objMatch As Object

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    'page address is stated in code
    objIE.Navigate "page name"
    objIE.Visible = True

    Do While objIE.Busy Or Not objIE.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Do Until objIE.document.readyState = "complete"
        DoEvents
    Loop

    strCont = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("span4")(0).innerHtml
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "<div>\s*<label for="".*?"">(.*?)</label>\s*(.+?)\s*?</div>"
        Set objMatches = .Execute(strCont)
        For Each objMatch In objMatches
            MsgBox objMatch.SubMatches(0) & " = " & objMatch.SubMatches(1)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

See XHTML parsing with RegExp [disclaimer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2165759).

Comment: It actually works. Thank you so much. Just one small thing: I am completely new to RegExp, and I'm having problem with "Patter" part. Can you please explain how it is structured and why?
Also what If I have more than I div inside of HTML code with name "span4"

Comment: Here is [the description of `.Pattern` property on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIbrary/f97kw5ka.aspx), and [this one](http://script-coding.com/WSH/RegExp.html#4.) I guess might be more appropriate.

Comment: If you have nested divs, please update your question with such html block, the code you have tried, it's resulting output and what's going wrong.

Comment: I have already found a way how to retrieve info from nested DIVs.
In line: IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("span4")(0).innerHTML"
I have just replaced "span4" with variable that will change according to other code. 
Same applies to line MsgBox objMatch.SubMatches(0) & " = " & objMatch.SubMatches(1)
I have just replaced number value after SubMatches and got what I wanted.
Anyhow - thank you for your help.

Comment: Hopefully last one question, regarding this topic.Default code looks like:
strCont = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("span4")(0).innerHTML
But I want to have a variable instead of "span4", in example
Dim1= "span4", I state following:
strCont = "objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName(" & Chr(34) & Dim1 & Chr(34) & ")(0).innerHTML"
It does not work. How can I make sure that this sting will be counted as exact code to be executed later in step:  
Set objMatches = .Execute(strCont)

Comment: Please update your question with that code to make it readable and with description and requirements. I'll take a look and update my answer.